# Does Docker provide any memory efficiency on top of a VM?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker

I have an application with a number of microservices and I'm trying to understand if Docker provides any memory advantages.  My services are Java 7/Tomcat 7.  Let's say I have 20 of them; is there any advantage for me to run Docker on top of an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 VM?  I understand the value of run-anywhere for developer workstations, etc.; my primary question/concern is about the VM memory footprint.  If I run each of these 20 services in their own container, with their own Tomcat, my assumption is that I'll need 20x the memory overhead for Tomcat, right?  If this is true, I'm trying to decide if Docker is of value or is more overhead than it's worth.  It seems like Docker's best value proposition is on top of a native OS, not as much in a VM; is there a different approach besides EC2 VM on AWS where Docker is best?

I'm curious how others would handle this situation or if Docker is even a solution in this space.  Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no memory advantage over running 20 Tomcat processes. The Docker daemon and ancillary processes for 'publishing' ports will consume extra memory.

Docker's advantage is over 20 VMs, which will consume vastly more memory. It provides more isolation than processes alone, e.g. each process will see its own filesystem, network interface, process space. Also Docker provides advantages for packaging and shipping software.